# Excel - Remove duplicates in a single cell (Non VBA method)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a non-VBA method to remove duplicates in a single cell. For example, in a cell I have values like **ABC, ABC, EFG, EFG, EFG, MN**, and i want my final output to be **ABC, EFG, MN**

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Excel, and observing that the separator is `comma-space`, you can try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(J1,", ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(.=following-sibling::*)]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Non-vba (and no formulas) ?

1 - You could separate text with comma, like csv file (shortcut is Alt + A + E)

2 - After this, transpose it, so every column will be line to line

3 - Then, you can remove duplicates

Hope my ideia helps you.

Comment: I'm not sure you've quite answered the question as to 'how to remove duplicates' - could you pls. consider elaborating on this point? (e.g. manually, through find and replace); also, assuming this shortcut is backward compatible / valid for all / any / certain versions of excel, how useful / robust would the solution be if values are not comma separated?